# How to pass a data to omnistudio flexcard from LWC while using NavigationMixIn.Navigate

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning, lwc

I have a requirement where I have to call a omnistudio flexcard from LWC and pass a row data on click of an id in a datatable. I'm trying to use navigationmixin.navigate to navigate to particular flexcard am able to navigate successfully but unable to pass row data. I have tried pusub but its not working. can anyone help me with this, please find my JS code below

```
handleRowAction(event) {

 const actionName = event.detail.action.name;

 const row = event.detail.row;

 console.log('action name ', actionName);

 console.log('row', row);

 switch (actionName) {

  case 'locationId':

  this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({

   type: 'standard__component',

   attributes: {

   componentName: 'omnistudio__vlocityLWCOmniWrapper'

   },

   state: {

   c__target: 'c:cfCNCFacilityLocationsDetailsPage',

   c__tabLabel: row.locationId

   }

  })

  pubsub.fire("CNCFacilityLocationsDetailsPage", "recordData", {

   rowData: row

  });

  break;

  default:

 }

 }
```